# LVM VG/LV is not activated at system startup

Tags: debian, lvm, scsi, multipath-storage

I have two multipath devices configured

```
mpathb (36005076300808b3e9000000000000007) dm-1 IBM,2145
size=16T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
| `- 1:0:1:1 sde 8:64 active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  `- 1:0:0:1 sdc 8:32 active ready running
mpatha (36005076300808b3e9000000000000006) dm-0 IBM,2145
size=16T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
| `- 1:0:0:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  `- 1:0:1:0 sdd 8:48 active ready running
```

For each of them I created a PV/VG/LV

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV                 VG  Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/mpatha vg0 lvm2 a--  <16.00t    0
  /dev/mapper/mpathb vg1 lvm2 a--  <16.00t    0
```

After rebooting, my VG/LV is not activated.

```
$ sudo systemctl status lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service
● lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service - LVM event activation on device 254:0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lvm2-pvscan@.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-04-11 21:58:53 MSK; 14min ago
       Docs: man:pvscan(8)
    Process: 803 ExecStart=/sbin/lvm pvscan --cache --activate ay 254:0 (code=exited, status=5)
   Main PID: 803 (code=exited, status=5)
        CPU: 10ms
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 systemd[1]: Starting LVM event activation on device 254:0...
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 lvm[803]:   pvscan[803] PV /dev/mapper/mpatha is duplicate for PVID un8VgmPbM5dheccMCCmmMzr4UGcO3Gau on 254:0 and 8:16.
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 lvm[803]:   pvscan[803] PV /dev/mapper/mpatha failed to create online file.
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 11 21:58:53 cephnode-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LVM event activation on device 254:0.
```

/etc/lvm/lvm.conf:

```
filter = [ "a|/dev/mapper/mpath.*|", "r|.*|" ]
```

What do I have to do to make the VG/LV activation work when I boot up the system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because LVM had opened the disk device for access first (before the multipath subsystem had a chance to do it), and still holds a handle for accessing the PV of `vg0` as just `/dev/sdb` (= major:minor device 8:16, as indicated by the error message) as opposed to `/dev/mapper/mpatha` (= major:minor device 254:0).

When a multipath device is opened, the multipath subsystem will attempt to get an exclusive lock for its component `/dev/sd*` devices, to prevent this from happening. But it won't be able to do so if LVM got to the `/dev/sdb` disk first and already has the disk device open when multipathing is started.

On Debian 11, if one of your LVM volume groups contains your root filesystem, you should make sure the `multipath-tools-boot` package is also installed; if your root filesystem is **not** on a multipathed disk, you should **not** install this package.

If you have not already done so after activating multipathing, you should update your initramfs file (with `sudo update-initramfs -u`), so your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` filter will also apply within initramfs.

To get rid of the error, you would have to deactivate and re-activate your volume group(s) now that multipathing is running, so LVM will start using the multipathed device instead of one of the individual path devices (`/dev/sd*`). But if your root filesystem is located on a multipathed disk, you cannot unmount it and will have to reboot.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We noticed this problem when upgraded our SAN connected server from RHEL 6.10 to RHEL 8.4.

SAN vg(created using multipath device) couldn't be activated. We had to do a vgexport/vgimport to fix this.